# Installing npm node-sass

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, node-sass

I have a project in vue.js. I can't install npm because I this error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/devel2   /Documents/vuejs/platzi-music/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/devel2/Documents/vuejs/platzi-music/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/devel2/Documents/vuejs/platzi-music/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v9.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried with:

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules
```

I resinstalled nodejs to 8.XX

```
 sudo npm node-sass -F
```

But anything working.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: please add some other info about your environment. Are you in linux?
Are you using a Virtual Machine? Vagrant? ...

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16. I am trying to install in local.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This solved my problem:
I was also running as root(with sudo) so NPM disables scripts automatically. Then passing the *--unsafe-perm* to the **npm install** command solved the whole thing. I was using it with Angular-Cli but the error was so similar.

```
sudo npm install node-sass --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: **Great!** love to help :D

Answer (score -3):

The error message you're encountering suggests that there's an issue with building the `node-sass` binary, and it's related to your development environment. It appears to be related to the absence of Xcode Command Line Tools on your Mac.

To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. **Install Xcode Command Line Tools:**

   Open your Terminal and run the following command to install the Xcode Command Line Tools:

   ```bash
   xcode-select --install
   ```

   This command will prompt you to install the tools. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation.
2. **Clear npm Cache:**

   After installing the Xcode Command Line Tools, it's a good practice to clear the npm cache to avoid any potential issues related to cached data. Run the following command:

   ```bash
   npm cache clean -f
   ```
3. **Retry the Installation:**

   Once the Xcode Command Line Tools are installed and the npm cache is cleared, you can retry installing `node-sass`:

   ```bash
   npm install node-sass
   ```

   This should hopefully resolve the issue, and `node-sass` should be installed successfully.

Comment: AI-generated answers are not accepted on this site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy